# Fixing contradiction in the Quadratic Equation

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, quadratics

> If the roots of $a{x}^{2}+bx+c$, where $a$ and $c$ are non-zero real numbers, be imaginary and the ratio of the roots be $r:1$, where $r>0$, then prove that $a$ and $c$ are of opposite signs.

My approach:
For roots being imaginary, we get ${b}^{2} - 4{a}{c}< 0$ (First condition)

Let the roots be $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. We know that $\alpha +\beta =\frac { -b }{ a } $ and $\alpha \beta =\frac { c }{ a }$.

Squaring the sum expression and dividing with the product's , we get:

$\frac { \alpha  }{ \beta  } +\frac { \beta  }{ \alpha  } +2=\frac { { b }^{ 2 } }{ ac } <4$ or $r+\frac { 1 }{ r } <2$.

As AM-GM is applicable for non-negative real numbers, we get $r+\frac { 1 }{ r } \ge 2$.

As observable, the intersection of both the conditions is $\phi $.

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong. Any hint or solution could be appreciated.

Comment: They did not tell you b is real necessarily, maybe that is relevant? Otherwise I agree that for real coefficients complex roots require a and c of the same sign.

Comment: @Ian No mention on the nature of $b$.

Comment: For imaginary roots: b^2 -4ac<0, b^2< 4ac, since b^2positive or 0, a,c must both be positive or both be negative.

Comment: @PeterSzilas I think the question needs to give more information about the nature of $b$, right?

Comment: SwapnilDas. Assumed that b was real in the comment. If b is complex, another story, right you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-(p+qi))(x-r(p+qi)),$$ where $\{p,q,\}\subset\mathbb R$.

Thus, we need to prove that $$(p+qi)^2<0,$$ which is $pq=0$ and $p^2-q^2<0$, which is obvious because roots are imaginary.

Comment: The solution is very fine. Kindly let me know the mistake in my inequality assumptions, and why does the intersections of the conditions turn out to be $\phi$.

Comment: @Swapnil Das By your reasoning $\frac{b^2}{ac}\geq4$ or $\frac{b^2-4ac}{ac}\geq0$ and since $b^2-4ac<0$, we obtain $ac<0$.

Comment: So, is the 'reasoning' correct? $ac <0$ is obtained.

Comment: @Swapnil Das Yes of course and your solution is very nice! You just need to delete "or $r+\frac{1}{r}<2$."

Comment: It's exactly exactly where I am confused. Why is that wrong?

Comment: @Swapnil Das See my previous comment. $\frac{b^2-4ac}{ac}\geq0$. Right?